# Retrofit change value of @Field in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I need to change value of @Field path in Retrofit.

```
@Field("select_animal[i][name]") String animalName
```

I need to change the value of "i" according to my for loop.

How do i achieve it?

Comment: Use FieldMap instead of Field

Answer (score 0):

You can add body in non-compile time, for example, when call this method